# Why does div display:table-row ignore margin?

Tags: html, css

The following html works as expected apart from margin-top being completely ignored by table row div. And I can't figure out why.

```
<div class='table'>

  <div class='margin-top5 row user' id='user_113'>
    <div class='cell left avatar margin-right5'><img alt="Blank_avatar_thumb" src="/images/blank_avatar_thumb.png?1295354025" /></div>
    <div class='cell left'>
      <div class='bold'><a href="/voisins/113">Dandre</a></div>
      <div class='small of_hidden'>toothpicking, veryveryveryveeerrrryyyyyylooooooooong, kidnapping...</div>
    </div>
    <div class='cell right'>42</div>

    <div class='clear'></div>
  </div>
  /* more rows */
</div>
```

css:

```
div.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
div.row {
  display: table-row;
}
div.cell {
  display: table-cell;
}
div.left {
  float: left;
}
div.right {
  float: right;
}
div.clear {
  clear: both;
}
.avatar {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.margin-top5 {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.margin-right5 {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.of_hidden {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.small {
  font-size: 0.8em;
}
body, p, ol, ul, td {
  font-family: verdana, arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 18px;
}
```

**EDIT**:

If I remove `.row` class from row div, it starts picking up margin-top.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is the cullprit: `display: table-row;`
You're telling the div to behave like a `tr`, `tr`'s don't have a `margin`... or `padding`.

You can apply a `padding` to a `td`, but not a `margin`.

Comment: That is very counterintuitive - it is div after all... And btw margin applies correctly to `display: table-cell;` (it is in the code sample)

Comment: Yes, the margin works for a div with `display: table-cell;` however you still cannot apply a margin to a `td` element. So then we have `display: table-row;` which behaves as if it were a `tr` and `display: table-cell;` which doesn't behave like a `td`... very counter intuitive indeed.

Comment: @artemave — it is not counterintuitive, there are lots of rules for which CSS properties may apply to elements based on the value of the display property applied to the element. There are none at all that are based on what the element is or what its *default* display value is.

Comment: @Quentin while your statement is true, i don't see how it's relevant.   it's _still_ counterintuitive that in this case you can apply margins to a cell but not a row.

Answer (score 2):

Use border-spacing: 10px; for the div with display:table;

Use this link for refference:
[space between divs - display table-cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346083/space-between-divs-display-table-cell)