# space between divs - display table-cell

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have here two divs:

```
<div style="display:table-cell" id="div1">
    content
</div>

<div style="display:table-cell" id="div2">
    content
</div>
```

Is there a way to make space between these two divs (that have `display:table-cell`)?

Answer (score 207, accepted):

You can use [`border-spacing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing) property:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Cell 1</div>
        <div class="cell">Cell 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.table {
  display: table;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 10px;
}

.row { display:table-row; }

.cell {
  display:table-cell;
  padding:5px;
  background-color: gold;
}
```

**[JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/icoy/1/edit)**

**Any other option?**

*Well*, not really.

**Why?**

- `margin` property [is not applicable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/margin) to `display: table-cell` elements.
- `padding` property doesn't create space between edges of the cells.
- `float` property destroys the expected behavior of `table-cell` elements which are able to be as tall as their parent element.

Comment: Any other option? Sure, `position: relative`.

Comment: @Jongosi According to [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-position): *The effect of `position: relative` on `table-*-group`, `table-row`, `table-column`, `table-cell`, and `table-caption` elements is undefined.*

Comment: You could also create a one-sided border the same colour as the background. `border-right: 10px solid #FFF`. This worked well for me when designing a CSS dropdown menu when I wanted some space between `table-cell` elements.

Comment: You can also add cells purely for spacing. Not ideal, but at least you avoid the headache of trying to turn off border-spacing on the rightmost cell.

Comment: I also wanted the "padding" to be on only 1 edge of the "cell", so I had to use armadadrive's solution except for I used a border color of rgba(0,0,0,0) for a transparent border so I don't have to worry about background color/image.  border-right: 10px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);

Answer (score 26):

Use transparent borders if possible.

### JSFiddle Demo

https://jsfiddle.net/74q3na62/

**HTML**

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Cell 1</div>
        <div class="cell">Cell 2</div>
        <div class="cell">Cell 3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.table {
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.row { display:table-row; }

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  background-color: gold;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}

.cell:last-child {
  border-right: 0 none;
}
```

### Explanation

You could use the `border-spacing` property, as the accepted answer suggests, but this not only generates space between the table cells but also between the table cells and the table container. This may be unwanted.

If you don't need visible borders on your table cells you should therefore use `transparent` borders to generate cell margins. Transparent borders require setting `background-clip: padding-box;` because otherwise the background color of the table cells is displayed on the border.

Transparent borders and background-clip are supported in IE9 upwards (and all other modern browsers). If you need IE8 compatibility or don't need actual transparent space you can simply set a white border color and leave the `background-clip` out.

Comment: The 'border-right' setting is actually enough to provide the space between, no "table" declaring is required.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="display:table;width:100%"  >
<div style="display:table-cell;width:49%" id="div1">
content
</div>

<!-- space between divs - display table-cell -->
<div style="display:table-cell;width:1%" id="separated"></div>
<!-- //space between divs - display table-cell -->

<div style="display:table-cell;width:50%" id="div2">
content
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the above does work, here is my solution that requires a little less markup and is more flexible.

```css
.cells {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding: 1px;
}
.cells>.content {
  background: #EEE;
  display: table-cell;
  float: left;
  padding: 3px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" class="cells"><div class="content">My Cell 1</div></div>
<div id="div2" class="cells"><div class="content">My Cell 2</div></div>
```

Answer (score -6):

Make a new div with whatever name (I will just use table-split) and give it a width, without adding content to it, while placing it between necessary divs that need to be separated.

You can add whatever width you find necessary. I just used 0.6% because it's what I needed for when I had to do this.

```css
.table-split {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 0.6%
}
```

```html
<div class="table-split"></div>
```

Comment: This is a terrible solution.

Comment: This was a common strategy when actual table elements were used for layout purposes, and part of the reason that methodology is now obsolete.

Comment: As it can be accomplished with css only, the html use should be avoid