# Why doesn't image fit the table cell

Tags: html, css

[image]

I am wondering why the image doesn't stretch the entire table cell?

Here is the code:

```
<td width="110" height="100" style="margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 1px solid rgb(0, 174, 239); background-color: #00FF00">
    <a target="_blank" href="http://mymed.com/provider.aspx?id=2611" xt="SPCLICKSTREAM" name="Kamin_1"><img style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: inline-block;" alt="s, kam, MD" border=0 src="http://mymed.com/images/email/Physicians/Kaminski.jpg" name="Cont_19" /></a>
</td>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the percentage value for [width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/width) and [height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/height) is related to containing block dimensions, and the anchor tag (the container) doesn't have any explicit width/height.

You'd need to display the anchor tag as `block` then apply then set its width/height to `100%` as well.

```css
a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Also, there would be [a gap below the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18428997/center-image-element-in-parent-div/18429014#18429014) because the image is aligned vertically in its baseline by default. In order to fix that you should align the image as follows:

```css
img { vertical-align: bottom; }
```

Also note that [`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/margin) [is not applicable to table cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346083/space-between-divs-display-table-cell/18346159#18346159); So you could remove the useless `margin: 0;` inline style from `<td>`.

Comment: Not working for me for some reason... The TD stretches over height now :/

Comment: @SiKni8 I didn't do anything to the `<td>` elements. Could you provide an online demo?

Comment: As you can see at the demo, the `td` has a height of `100px`.

Comment: @HashemQolami Everyone who answered here are absolutely correct. The issue was the text was extending beyond the table which caused the image to have the white space :/ SILLY ME!!!

Comment: @SiKni8 Ah.. I thought you want to stretch the image to fill the entire vertical space of the cell.

Comment: I did, just forgot to add the rest of the TD. Laziness made me pay and delayed the solution lol

Comment: @SiKni8 problem may have come from `vertical-align: botom;` as it should read `vertical-align: bottom;` (with two t's).

Comment: @PubliDesign Ah I missed that while I was typing the answer. BTW the fiddle is correct :)

Comment: @HashemQolami No worries, just thought this was why it didn't work for SiKni8. Also, I see you updated your post, smart move, especially that you've got the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

To ensure it covers the whole area, I would remove the `width:100%;height:100%` and add this to my CSS:

```
td { position: relative; }
td img { position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; }
```

Although this could world, I really don't think this is ideal since it could stretch images if they aren't the exact size of your `td`.

Comment: @Pubil Design Everyone who answered here are absolutely correct. The issue was the text was extending beyond the table which caused the image to have the white space :/ SILLY ME!!!

Answer (score 1):

Why not do:

```
<td width="110" height="100" style="margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 1px solid rgb(0, 174, 239); background-color: #00FF00;">
    <a target="_blank" href="http://mymed.com/provider.aspx?id=2611" xt="SPCLICKSTREAM" name="Kamin_1" style='width:100%;height:100%;background-image:url(http://mymed.com/images/email/Physicians/Kaminski.jpg);display:block;'></a>
</td>
```

This sets the `a` element to `display:block` and gives it the same height and width of the parent `td` with the image as its background.

In production, you should also look at setting your styles into a stylesheet as opposed to being inline.

e.g.

```
td.bios{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 174, 239);
  background-color: #00FF00;
}

td.bios a.imgLink{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display:block;
}

<td class='bios'>
    <a target="_blank" href="http://mymed.com/provider.aspx?id=2611" xt="SPCLICKSTREAM" name="Kamin_1" style='background-image:url(http://mymed.com/images/email/Physicians/Kaminski.jpg)' class='imgLink'></a>
</td>
```

Comment: Percentage values refer to the [width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/width)/[height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/height) of the containing block. Not the element itself.

Comment: @SW4 Everyone who answered here are absolutely correct. The issue was the text was extending beyond the table which caused the image to have the white space :/ SILLY ME!!!

Answer (score 1):

It's keeping the images' proportions. To fill the entire cell would mean stretching the images.